# Redux props not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Hi I'm trying Redux recently. I wanted to build a counter for practice. 
It's composed of two buttons(plus & minus) and a counter showing the current number.

The action creators and reducers are connected to the corresponding components. The store is also connected to the provider. Yet I don't know why but the initial number(state passed as props to the counter component) is not showing?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Yumichen/pen/qjwYBp?editors=0010)

Javascript:

```
/*--Reducers--*/
const reducer_num = (state=0,action)=>{
  switch(action.type){
    case "PLUS":
    case "MINUS":
      return state + action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const rootReducer = Redux.combineReducers({
  num: reducer_num
});

/*--Action creators--*/
const action_plus = ()=>{
  return {
    type: "PLUS",
    payload: 1
  };
}

const action_minus = ()=>{
  return {
    type: "MINUS",
    payload: -1
  };
}

/*--Components & containers--*/
//counter
const Counter = (props)=>{
  return (<div className="counter">{props.num}</div>);
}

const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
  return {num: state.num};
}

ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps)(Counter);

//plus
const Plus = (props)=>{
  return (<div className="plus" onClick={props.plus}>+</div>);
}

const mapDispatchToProps_plus = (dispatch)=>{
  return Redux.bindActionCreators({plus: action_plus},dispatch);
}

ReactRedux.connect(mapDispatchToProps_plus)(Plus);

//minus
const Minus = (props)=>{
  return (<div onClick={props.minus} className="minus">-</div>);
}

const mapDispatchToProps_minus = (dispatch)=>{
  return Redux.bindActionCreators({minus: action_minus},dispatch);
}

ReactRedux.connect(mapDispatchToProps_minus)(Minus);

// Provider & store
const Provider = ReactRedux.Provider,
      store = Redux.createStore(rootReducer);
//App
const App = ()=>{
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
    <div className="container">
    <Plus/>
    <Counter/>
    <Minus/>
    </div>
      </Provider>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.body);
```

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few issues with your code,

**First:** `mapDispatchToProps` is second argument to `connect` function and when you don't have a `mapStateToProps` function, you need to pass the first argument as null

**Second:** `connect` returns a Component connected to the store that you need to make use of but you are not using that

Complete Code:

```
/*--Reducers--*/
const reducer_num = (state=0,action)=>{
  switch(action.type){
    case "PLUS":
    case "MINUS":
       console.log(action.type)
      return state + action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const rootReducer = Redux.combineReducers({
  num: reducer_num
});

/*--Action creators--*/
const action_plus = ()=>{
  return {
    type: "PLUS",
    payload: 1
  };
}

const action_minus = ()=>{
  console.log('minus')
  return {
    type: "MINUS",
    payload: -1
  };
}

/*--Components & containers--*/
//counter
let Counter = (props)=>{
  return (<div className="counter">{props.num}</div>);
}

const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
  return {num: state.num};
}

Counter = ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps)(Counter);

//plus
let Plus = (props)=>{
  return (<div className="plus" onClick={props.plus}>+</div>);
}

const mapDispatchToProps_plus = (dispatch)=>{
  return Redux.bindActionCreators({plus: action_plus},dispatch);
}

Plus = ReactRedux.connect(null,mapDispatchToProps_plus)(Plus);

//minus
let Minus = (props)=>{
  console.log(props);
  return (<div onClick={props.minus} className="minus">-</div>);
}

const mapDispatchToProps_minus = (dispatch)=>{
  return Redux.bindActionCreators({minus: action_minus},dispatch);
}

Minus=ReactRedux.connect(null,mapDispatchToProps_minus)(Minus);

// Provider & store
const Provider = ReactRedux.Provider,
      store = Redux.createStore(rootReducer);
//App
const App = ()=>{
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
    <div className="container">
    <Plus/>
    <Counter/>
    <Minus/>
    </div>
      </Provider>
  );
}

  ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.body);
```

**[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rwgpYm?editors=0011)**

Comment: Thank you! I understand now

Answer (score 1):

You code of `Counter` component should look like this:

```
let Counter = (props)=>{
  return (<div className="counter">{props.num}</div>);
}

Counter = ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps)(Counter);
```

You have to render component returned by the `connect` function. Similar mistake is in `Plus` and `Minus`.

You have provided `mapDispatchToProps_minus` as the first argument for `Plus` and `Minus` component which is wrong. First argument should be `mapStateToProps`

```
const mapStateToProps = () => ({})
ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps_minus)(Minus);
```

Answer (score 1):

I m not sure but i just used your Codepen and it seems that you forgot to pass props to your counter component.

if you do
    Counter num={4}

then it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

You create connected components but you never assign them to variables, and you put the old 'dumb' components in the main component that you render to the DOM.

[I've created a fixed version of your CodePen.](https://codepen.io/arrow7000/pen/OgYzgY?editors=0011)

```
/*--Reducers--*/
const reducer_num = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "PLUS":
    case "MINUS":
      return state + action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const rootReducer = Redux.combineReducers({
  num: reducer_num
});

/*--Action creators--*/
const action_plus = () => {
  return {
    type: "PLUS",
    payload: 1
  };
};

const action_minus = () => {
  return {
    type: "MINUS",
    payload: -1
  };
};

/*--Components & containers--*/
//counter
const Counter = props => {
  return <div className="counter">{props.num}</div>;
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { num: state.num };
};

const CounterContainer = ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps)(Counter);

//plus
const Plus = props => {
  return <div className="plus" onClick={props.plus}>+</div>;
};

const mapDispatchToProps_plus = dispatch => {
  return Redux.bindActionCreators({ plus: action_plus }, dispatch);
};

const PlusContainer = ReactRedux.connect(mapDispatchToProps_plus)(Plus);

//minus
const Minus = props => {
  return <div onClick={props.minus} className="minus">-</div>;
};

const mapDispatchToProps_minus = dispatch => {
  return Redux.bindActionCreators({ minus: action_minus }, dispatch);
};

const MinusContainer = ReactRedux.connect(mapDispatchToProps_minus)(Minus);

// Provider & store
const Provider = ReactRedux.Provider,
  store = Redux.createStore(rootReducer);
//App
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div className="container">
        <PlusContainer />
        <CounterContainer />
        <MinusContainer />
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```